# RadComboBox Doesn't Collapse on Click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, telerik

When you click on a typical ComboBox, it expands. When you click it again, it collapse.

When you click on a RadComboBox, it expands. When you click it again, nothing happens. That is, unless you click on the arrow or actually make a selection.

I want my RadComboBoxes to collapse when they are clicked a second time, just like a regular ComboBox would. Since the RadComboBoxes are transformed into a whole mess of HTML with their own CSS styles, I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Here is how I am declaring the control.

```
public static RadComboBox makeARadicalBox() {
    RadComboBox cmbo = new RadComboBox();
    cmbo.ID = "MyRadicalComboBox";

    List<string> listItems = getListItems();
    foreach (string s in listItems)
        cmbo.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(s));

    cmbo.Skin = "myRadicalSkin";

    // TODO - Make the *entire* box clickable instead of just the little arrow

    return cmbo; 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you click inside text entry portion of the box a second time, you want it to collapse?  Please clarify where you click when you say "When you click on a RadComboBox".

Comment: I see what you mean.  Based on this site http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/programming/clientevents/defaultcs.aspx, there is no event for when you click the header box.  Closing it by reclicking it will need some sort of work around not directly provided by Telerik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  When you click the RadComboBox, if the drop-down is open then hide the drop-down, otherwise show the drop-down.  The `mouseup` part is then so that it doesn't flicker (quickly open/close).

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onLoad(sender) {
        var div = sender.get_element();

        $telerik.$(div).mousedown(function (e) {
            if (sender.get_dropDownVisible()) {
                sender.hideDropDown();
            }
            else {
                sender.showDropDown();
            }
        });

        $telerik.$(div).mouseup(function (e) {
            if (!sender.get_dropDownVisible()) {
                sender.hideDropDown();
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

.aspx:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="RadComboBox1" 
ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="false" OnClientLoad="onLoad">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="FoodStorage" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Freezer" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Fridge" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Microwave" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="OnTheGo" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Pantry" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: Since I was generating my combo boxes in code behind, I had to fiddle with the code a little, but your answer ultimately showed me the solution! I solved the flickering problem you mentioned with `cmbo.ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick = false;` and then instead of needing two events for mousedown and mouseup, I only needed one called click. Thank you *so* much!